# delete query wont work php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am able to get my edit button working but when i try and click the delete button it reloads the page and nothing happens.

html

```
<table width='80%' border=0>
    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Voucher</td>

    </tr>
    <?php 

        $vouchlist = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM vouchers");
    while($resvouch = mysqli_fetch_array($vouchlist)) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$resvouch['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$resvouch['voucher']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"editvoucher.php?id=$resvouch[id]\">Edit</a> | 
                  <a href=\"deletevoucher.php?id=$resvouch[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";        
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

deletevoucher.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
//deleting the row from table
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM vouchers WHERE id = $id ");
header("Location:protected_page.php");
```

---

EDIT:

added this to my deletevoucher. i get this "2Data added successfully.
Back to Admin Page." returned. i get the value that i click on my main php page. but it still is not deleteing...

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

// checking empty fields
if(empty($id) ) {                
    if(empty($id)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>voucher id is empty.</font><br/>";
    }


    //link to the previous page
    echo "<br/><a href='~Airways/protected_page.php'>Go Back</a>";
} else { 
    // if all the fields are filled (not empty)             
    //insert data to database
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM vouchers WHERE (id) = ('$id') ");


    //display success message
    echo $id;
    echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
    echo "<br/><a href='protected_page.php'>Back to Admin Page.</a>";
}
```

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXnO9.png)

Comment: 1.Are you sure id is coming in Url correctly? 2.Also you never checks for errors.3.Your delete query is wide open for `SQL INJECTION` so use `prepared statements`.

Comment: Do you any error ? Also share query with id .

Comment: no errors pop up, no information no anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table width='80%' border=0>
    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Voucher</td>

    </tr>
    <?php 

        $vouchlist = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM vouchers");
    while($resvouch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vouchlist)) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$resvouch['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$resvouch['voucher']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"editvoucher.php?id=$resvouch['id']\">Edit</a> | 
                  <a href=\"deletevoucher.php?id=$resvouch['id']\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";        
    }
    ?>
</table> 


$id = $_GET['id'];
//deleting the row from table
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM vouchers WHERE id = '".$id."' ");
header("Location:protected_page.php");
```

Comment: I just tried, no luck. I have no clue why it doesnt work. when i hover over the delete button it shows deletevoucher?id=1 (the value i hovered)

Comment: try deletion manually like $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM vouchers WHERE id = 1 ");

Comment: when i do that it get sstuck up on deletevoucher?id=1 page. and does nothing

Comment: check you table if it has column as id , and try executing this query in phpmy admin.

Comment: it works when i do it manually

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer try.

Comment: i tried what u did, it didnt work. i updated my question please have a look

Comment: Try turning errors on by adding error_reporting(E_ALL); on top of script

Comment: Show us your table structure.

Comment: try adding if($result){header("Location:protected_page.php");
 }

Comment: i posted a picture of my table structure above. and nothing gets reported with turning errors on.

Comment: has delete button correct link, check if it is passing value in id

Comment: it passes in the value when i use echo $id. possible to skype,discord or something

Comment: I did it. my user account on phpmyadmin didnt have delete privs.

Comment: Ok great you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the $result condition is true or false e.g
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,     "DELETE FROM vouchers WHERE      id = '$id'");
    if($result){
    header("Location:                            protectedpage.php");

Answer (score -1):

1 First, you should check for errors.

2 You should also check if 'id' value is been passed, using,

If (isset($_GET['id']){

// your cold here

}

3 The id value you passed in your url $resvouch[id]
   Should carry a single column like this;

$resvouch['id'].

4 Change your query to;

```
"DELETE FROM vochers WHERE id = '$id.";
```

Comment: No errors appear, nothing appears with isset no matter what i put. and my code 500s when i single column it